# Flag condition and file writing

Tags: c++

I am creating a hotel management system software for my college project.There are two primary problems with the code.

1. The program takes in a room number, runs it through the check function and if according to the condition books it, However when I try to book again with a unique room number it says it has been booked even though it hasn't been in reality.It only books rooms one time.
2. The function of book_rooms is not writing contents to the file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct hotel
{
    int room_no[50];
    string name[50] ;
    string adress[50];
    int mobile_no[50];
    int bill[50];
    int days[50];
    int room;
    int room1;
    int flag=0;
    fstream records;

void main_menu();
int book_rooms();
int customer_records();
int rooms_alloted();
int edit_records();
int customer_bills();
int check(int);
};

void hotel :: main_menu()
{
    int choice;
while(choice!=6)
{

  system("cls");
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t*************************";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t HOTEL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM ";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t      * MAIN MENU *";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t*************************";
cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t1.Book A Room";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t2.Customer Records";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t3.Rooms Allotted";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t4.Edit Record";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t5.Customer Bills";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t6.Exit";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tEnter Your Choice: ";
cin>>choice;
switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    {
        book_rooms();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        customer_records();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        rooms_alloted();
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        edit_records();
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        customer_bills();
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        break;
    }
}

}
}
int hotel:: book_rooms()
{
    
    system("cls");
    int room;
    cout<<"\n\t*************************";
    cout<<"\n\t     ROOM BOOKING";
    cout<<"\n\t*************************";
    cout<<"\n\nPlease enter the room number you want to book.";
    cout<<"\n1: Standard room(Room 1-20) (Rs.1000/night)";
    cout<<"\n2.Suite(Room 21-40) (Rs.5000/night)";
    cout<<"\n3.Luxury Room(Room 41-50) (Rs.10000/night)\n";
    ofstream records("rooms.txt");



    cin>>room;
    room1=room-1;

    flag=check(room);



    if(flag==1)
    {
        cout<<"Sorry this room has been taken";
        system("pause");
    }

    else{

            room_no[room-1]=room;

    records<<"Room "<<room_no[room-1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Name:";
    getline(cin, name[room-1]);
    getline(cin, name[room-1]);
    records<<name[room-1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Adress:";
    getline(cin, adress[room-1]);
    records<<adress[room-1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nMobile no: ";
    cin>>mobile_no[room-1];
    records<<mobile_no[room-1]<<"\n";
    records.close();
    cout<<"\nYour room has been booked\n";
    system("pause");
}}
int hotel::check(int r)
{
ifstream records("rooms.txt");
while(!records.eof())
{


records>>room_no[r-1];
if(room_no[r-1]==r)
    {
    flag=1;
    break;

    }
    }

records.close();
return flag;

}




int main()
{
    hotel p;
    p.main_menu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems very likely there are multiple problems with this code. But your immediate problem seems to be that you are opening `"rooms.txt"` for input and output simultaneously.

```
int hotel::book_rooms()
{
    ...
    ofstream records("rooms.txt");
    ...
    flag=check(room);
    ...
}

int hotel::check(int r)
{
    ifstream records("rooms.txt");
    ...
}
```

See the problem? `book_rooms` immediately opens rooms.txt for output and then `check` tries to open the same file for input. Reorganize your code like this so you are not opening the file in two places at the same time.

```
int hotel::book_rooms()
{
    ...
    flag=check(room);
    ...
    ofstream records("rooms.txt");
    ...
}

int hotel::check(int r)
{
    ifstream records("rooms.txt");
    ...
}
```

But as I say I think you are going to find this is only the first of multiple problems with this code. It seems you are trying to be too ambitious and writing too much code without enough testing. It's a very common failing of beginners.